# Migrate Windows 2012 R2 domain controller to another Windows 2012 R2 domain controller on different network

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am planning to migrate our existing domain controllers from one network to the other. My plan is to build new domain controllers in other network and allow Domain controller to replicate. There is no firewall between two networks.
I had a looked at this link:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/04/02/step-by-step-active-directory-migration-from-windows-server-2003-to-windows-server-2012.aspx 
This link gives instructions to migrate from 2003 to 2012. 
My question is does the same instructions apply to 2012 to 2012 migration?

Is the step "Changing Schema master" needs to be performed on all primary and backup domain controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you are simply adding new DCs all you should need to do is add the DCs, replicate, move any FSMO roles, then demote the old DCs. However you can skip the regsvr part if you transfer the role on the machine its already registered on.

Comment: What's regsvr? Do I need to change schema master according to the article?

Comment: The article refers to using regsvr32 to manage the schema. Yes you need to move the schema master prior to retirement.

Answer (score 1):

All 5 FSMO roles need to be migrated to your new DCs, including the Schema Master, however you only need to move each role once.